# AutosizeColumns on SXSSFWorkbook

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, apache-poi

Is it possible to autoSizeColumns on a streaming SXSSFWorkbook?
I implemented an export functionality to export a list of objects to excel. At first I used the XSSFWorkbook (not streaming) and after all the cells were created, I autosized all the columns, resulting in a nice excel file.

For performance issues we wanted to change the workbook to the streaming version, but this resulted in a NullPointer at org.apache.poi.ss.util.SheetUtil.getCellWidth.

Is it possible to call autoSizeColumns for a SXSSFWorkbook?

Im using poi-ooxml 3.9, but I have the same issue in 3.8.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You need to make sure every cell has a value.

We use the following code to set a string value to a cell:

```
Cell c = row.createCell(i);
c.setCellValue(text == null ? "" : text );
```

** Cell should never be null values else it throws NullPointerException. Hence set the value as shown above.

Thanks a lot, this helped!!

Comment: I used streaming api of poi 3.14, but encountered ' Could not auto-size column. Make sure the column was tracked prior to auto-sizing the column.' when I called autoSizeColumn. Did you ever meet it?

Comment: I had this error also, liam xu. Call trackAllColumnsForAutoSizing() on the SXSSFSheet object before calling autoSizeColumn(columnIndex) and it will be fixed.

Comment: NOTE: As per documentation, track required columns before writing one or more rows to the sheet. i.e. call trackColumnForAutoSizing() first, then write rows using createRow(), and finally call autoSizeColumn(). Hope this comment adds some value.

Answer (score 5):

sheet.trackAllColumnsForAutoSizing();

Answer (score 4):

Use **sheet.isColumnTrackedForAutoSizing(0);**
 for first and subsequently used for other column, i have faced exception whenever code executed autoSizeColumn(0) get executed. by using above code i have resolved the issue and it's good to expand the column width too based on the text.

Answer (score 0):

sheet.trackAllColumnsForAutoSizing(), this works but it is truly not a good approach. Because if you are working with lakhs of data, it delays the process of writing to file by huge margin

Comment: Use it only once, before write to file.

Answer (score -2):

**Error: NullPointerException** on `org.apache.poi.ss.util.SheetUtil.getCellWidth(SheetUtil.java:122)`

Fix: Always set value to Cell as shown below, it throws NullPointerException when there is null in Cell, so set the value as:

```
Cell c = row.createCell(i);
c.setCellValue(text == null ? "" : text );
```