# How can i handle the auto size issue in a java report usinig poi 3.15?

Tags: java

trying to export on one excel file using this method:

```
private Sheet activeSheet;
public void addText(int column, int rowNumber, String s) throws Exception {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Row row = activeSheet.getRow(rowNumber);
    if(row==null){
        row = activeSheet.createRow(rowNumber);
    }
    Cell cell = row.createCell(column);

    s = ToolUtils.nn(s);
    if(s.indexOf("\n")!=-1){
        int nbLines = StringUtils.countMatches(s, "\n") ;
        CellStyle cs = workbook.createCellStyle();
        cs.setWrapText(true);
        //cs.set
        cell.setCellStyle(cs);
        row.setHeightInPoints(((nbLines+1)*activeSheet.getDefaultRowHeightInPoints()));
        activeSheet.autoSizeColumn(column);

    }

    //cell.setCellValue(s);
    cell.setCellValue(s == null ? "" : s);
}
```

I have got this error:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not auto-size column. Make sure the column was tracked prior to auto-sizing the column

I have try to call this methode:

`trackAllColumnsForAutoSizing()` to fix the issue but it does not work as know method for the sheet interface. Shall I upgrade the `apache poi` version? 
what shall I do do fix the method that insert data into the excel columns?

Comment: just as other remarque when I try to call the methode trackAllColumnsFor AutoSizing() : alwyes I have got this : The method trackAllColumnsForAutoSizing() is undefined for the type SXSSFSheet !!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14497082/autosizecolumns-on-sxssfworkbook
Refer this may this help.

Comment: unfortunatly not , I have  updated on my methode to make sure the cells are not empty .. but it does not solve the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

may not be exactly related, but you can try this:

```
        sheet.trackAllColumnsForAutoSizing();
    for (int i = 0; i < 11; i++) {
        sheet.autoSizeColumn(i);
    }
```

("i" should be less than your column numbers)

Answer (score 3):

```
private SXSSFSheet activeSheet;
public void addText(int column, int rowNumber, String s) throws Exception {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

ActiveSheet=workbook.createSheet();
    Row row = activeSheet.getRow(rowNumber);
    if(row==null){
        row = activeSheet.createRow(rowNumber);
    }
    Cell cell = row.createCell(column);
cell.setCellValue(s == null ? "" : s);
    s = ToolUtils.nn(s);
    if(s.indexOf("\n")!=-1){
        int nbLines = StringUtils.countMatches(s, "\n") ;
        CellStyle cs = workbook.createCellStyle();
        cs.setWrapText(true);
        //cs.set
        cell.setCellStyle(cs);
        row.setHeightInPoints(((nbLines+1)*activeSheet.getDefaultRowHeightInPoints()));
   activeSheet.trackColumnsForAutoSizing();    activeSheet.autoSizeColumn(column);

    }



}
```

Try this once may this helps you
There may be some syntax error just resolved/adjust those in your IDE.

Comment: any other suggestions ?

Comment: Before autoresize() try  use trackColumnsForAutoSizing()

Comment: This is known issue of Api and gets fixed in POI 3.15-beta2 via

Comment: ((SXSSFSheet) activeSheet).trackColumnsForAutoSizing();
      activeSheet.autoSizeColumn(column) .... I have try this but i have got "The method trackColumnsForAutoSizing() is undefined for the type SXSSFSheet" ...Shall I change the API version

Comment: Try activesheet.trackColumnforAutoSizing(int column ), you can try by cntrl+space in your IDE if eclipe/intellij/Rad

Comment: Even doc of Api says this Call trackAllColumnsForAutoSizing() on the SXSSFSheet object before calling autoSizeColumn(columnIndex) and it will be fixed

Comment: the method trackColumnsForAutoSizing(int) is undefined for the type Sheet..this what I get

Comment: private Sheet activeSheet; // I have made a cast as this ((SXSSFSheet) activeSheet).trackColumnsForAutoSizing(); // but it return that message : The method trackColumnsForAutoSizing() is undefined for the type SXSSFSheet"

Comment: private Sheet activeSheet change this to private SXSSFSheet activeSheet

Comment: rearlly many thanks for you help .. but I have alwayes this error :The method trackColumnsForAutoSizing(int) is undefined for the type SXSSFSheet

Comment: Even after changing sheet to SXSSFSHEET?

Comment: Make that thing to activeSheet =workbook.createSheet();

Comment: I have alwyes same issue :'(

Comment: Could you please share me your import

Comment: Sharing imports?

Comment: what do you mean by sharing import ? sorry but I have not get it ?

Comment: It's OK, if this starts working then please let me know what was the root cause.

Answer (score 1):

```
public void addText(int column, int rowNumber, String s) throws Exception {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Row row = activeSheet.getRow(rowNumber);
    if(row==null){
        row = activeSheet.createRow(rowNumber);
    }
    Cell cell = row.createCell(column);
    s = ToolUtils.nn(s);



    if(s.indexOf("\n")!=-1){
        int nbLines = StringUtils.countMatches(s, "\n") ;
        CellStyle cs = workbook.createCellStyle();
        cs.setWrapText(true);
        //cs.set
        cell.setCellStyle(cs);
        row.setHeightInPoints(((nbLines+1)*activeSheet.getDefaultRowHeightInPoints()));
        activeSheet.trackColumnsForAutoSizing(column);
        activeSheet.autoSizeColumn(column);


    }

    //cell.setCellValue(s);
    cell.setCellValue(s == null ? "" : s);

}
```