# Could Not Auto-size Column in p:dataExporter

Tags: jsf, primefaces, apache-poi

I'm trying to use PrimeFaces DataExporter to export an `xlsxstream` type of file, but I seem to be getting this error:

```
WARNING: Could not auto-size column. Make sure the column was tracked prior to auto-sizing the column.
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not auto-size column. Make sure the column was tracked prior to auto-sizing the column.
    at org.apache.poi.xssf.streaming.SXSSFSheet.autoSizeColumn(SXSSFSheet.java:1606)
    at org.apache.poi.xssf.streaming.SXSSFSheet.autoSizeColumn(SXSSFSheet.java:1560)
    at org.primefaces.component.export.ExcelExporter.export(ExcelExporter.java:85)
    at org.primefaces.component.export.DataExporter.processAction(DataExporter.java:145)
    at javax.faces.event.ActionEvent.processListener(ActionEvent.java:88)
    ...
```

Any idea how to debug this, or what the cause might be?

Comment: This feels like a bug in the PF implementation of XLSX.  I would report it on the GitHub issues page with your sample XHTML snippet and this exception.

Comment: No, no 'snippets'... a full [mcve].... and version info

Comment: Looks like it can be fixed: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14497082/autosizecolumns-on-sxssfworkbook/14497475 . But I think that will have to be fixed in the PF code.  However you can try making sure none of your col/row values are NULL instead make them empty string "".

Comment: Seems like replacing 'xlsxstream' with 'xslx' provided a quick fix for me here

Comment: That is a quick fix but your app will now use way more memory generating your XLSX as long as you are OK with that.  I think I am going to report and fix this bug in Primefaces.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bug reported to PrimeFaces: https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/issues/4034

I fixed it for PF 6.3: https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/pull/4035